# Why Some(null) isn't considered None?

Tags: scala, null, scala-option

I am curious:

```
scala> Some(null) == None
res10: Boolean = false
```

Why isn't `Some(null)` transformed to `None`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should use `Option(null)` to reach the desired effect and return `None`.

`Some(null)` just creates a new `Option` with a defined value (hence `Some`) which is actually `null`, and there are few valid reasons to ever create one like this in real code.

Comment: This doesn't explain much... could you be more explicit?

Comment: @Mauricio Daniel has a nice example of why `Some(null)` should not be transformed to `None`.

Answer (score 33):

Unfortunately, `null` is a valid value for any `AnyRef` type -- a consequence of Scala's interoperability with Java. So a method that takes an object of type `A` and, internally, store it inside an `Option`, might well need to store a `null` inside that option.

For example, let's say you have a method that takes the head of a list, checks if that head correspond to a key in a store, and then return true if it is. One might implement it like this:

```
def isFirstAcceptable(list: List[String], keys: Set[String]): Boolean =
    list.headOption map keys getOrElse false
```

So, here's the thing... if the that inside `list` and `keys` come from some Java API, they both may well contain `null`! If `Some(null)` wasn't possible, then `isFirstAcceptable(List[String](null), Set[String](null))` would return `false` instead of `true`.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Arguably `null` shouldn't exist at all in Scala, and every Java-to-Scala interface would require wrapping the Java types in `Option`. (This is actually how some languages without `null`, such as Rust, provide interop with languages that have `null`.)

Answer (score 20):

I think the others in the thread do a good job explaining why `Some(null)` "should" exist, but if you happen to be getting `Some(null)` somewhere and want a quick way to turn it into `None`, I've done this before:

```
scala> val x: Option[String] = Some(null)
x: Option[String] = Some(null)

scala> x.flatMap(Option(_))
res8: Option[String] = None
```

And when the starting `Option` is a legit non-null value things work as you probably want:

```
scala> val y: Option[String] = Some("asdf")
y: Option[String] = Some(asdf)

scala> y.flatMap(Option(_))
res9: Option[String] = Some(asdf)
```

Comment: Indeed the 'why' is interesting, but most of us probably are more like 'what to do next'. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 15):

Much of Scala's WTFs can be attributed to its need for compatibility with Java. `null` is often used in Java as a value, indicating, perhaps the absence of a value. For example `hashMap.get(key)` will return `null` if the key is not matched.

With this in mind, consider the following possible values from wrapping a null returning method in an `Option`:

```
if (b) Some(hashMap.get(key)) else None
// becomes -->
None // the method was not invoked;
Some(value) // the method was invoked and a value returned; or
Some(null) // the method was invoked and null was returned.
```

`Some(null)` seems sufficiently distinct from `None` in this case to warrant allowing it in the language.

Of course if this is not desirable in your case then simply use:

```
if (b) Option(hashMap.get(key)) else None
// becomes -->
None // the method was not invoked or the mapped value was null; or
Some(value) // the method was invoked and a value returned
```

Comment: "Much of Scala's WTFs can be attributed to its need for compatibility with Java"... In java there's only one instance of Optional.EMPTY. If you have an optional which has different identity than Optional.EMPTY, you are guaranteed that it will not have null wrapped. This WTF, as you call, is absent in Java but present in Scala.

Comment: Not a lot of things are worse than three state booleans.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple thought experiment, consider two lists of Strings, one of length 5 and one of length 20.

Because we're running on the JVM, it's possible to insert `null` as a valid element into one of these lists - so put that in the long list as element #10

What, then, should the difference be in the values returned from the two following expressions?

**EDIT:** Exchanged `get` for `lift`, I was thinking of maps...

```
shortList.lift(10) //this element doesn't exist
longList.lift(10)  //this element exists, and contains null
```

Comment: The former throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Synesso - `shortList(10)` will throw an exception, true. But that's not what I'm doing...

Comment: Apologies, I assumed you were talking about java.util.List as your argument seemed similar to my own. I assumed too much!

Comment: @Synesso - Ahh, well, using Java's Lists comes with a whole different set of issues, and is *very* ill-advised!

Answer (score 2):

Because Option is considered to be a Functor and being a Functor means:

1. Has `unit` function (`apply` or just `Option("blah")` in Scala)
2. Has `map` function which transforms value from `T=>B` but not a context
3. Obeys 2 Functor laws - identity law and associative law

In this topic the main part is #2 - `Option(1).map(t=>null)` can not transform context. `Some` should remain. Otherwise it brakes associative law!

Just consider the following laws example:

```
def identity[T](v: T) = v
def f1(v: String) = v.toUpperCase
def f2(v: String) = v + v
def fNull(v: String): String = null

val opt = Option("hello")

//identity law
opt.map(identity) == opt //Some(hello) == Some(hello)

//associative law
opt.map(f1 _ andThen f2) == opt.map(f1).map(f2) //Some(HELLOHELLO) == Some(HELLOHELLO)
opt.map(fNull _ andThen f2) == opt.map(fNull).map(f2) //Some(nullnull) == Some(nullnull)
```

But what if `Option("hello").map(t=>null)` produced `None`? Associative law would be broken:

```
opt.map(fNull _ andThen f2) == opt.map(fNull).map(f2) //Some(nullnull) != None
```

That is my thought, might be wrong