# Is there any use of Some(x) over Option(x)?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, option-type

So in Scala `Some` and `None` are the two sub-classes of `Option`.

To get an instance of `Some`, you can do both `Some(x)` or `Option(x)`

```
scala> val x = "Foo"
x: String = Foo

scala> Some(x)
res0: Some[String] = Some(Foo)

scala> Option(x)
res1: Option[String] = Some(Foo)
```

So it looks like there's not much difference.
But of course if x is null, then they behave differently.

```
scala> val x:String = null
x: String = null

scala> Some(x)
res0: Some[String] = Some(null)

scala> Option(x)
res1: Option[String] = None
```

So it looks like, unless you want to preserve the null (for whatever reason), `Option(x)` is always preferable, because it's safer.

Even with literals, while we know for sure that `Some("foo")` cannot yield null, if later the string is extracted to a variable, you have to change it to `Option` to stay safe.

**My question: Other than preserving null, is there any reason to use `Some(x)`?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796616/why-somenull-isnt-considered-none

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few different reasons for using it:

1. It makes you realize what you're returning in a function.  Let's say you have a function that might return a null value.  You want to use an `Option` for this.  You should write your code in such a way that you know whether you're returning a `None` or a `Some` because otherwise you might not know what's going on, and you're relying on the construction for `Option` to do that work for you, which may not do what you expect.
2. When using a `match` statement, you need to have the difference to be able to choose between `Some` and a `None` because that's the whole point of using an `Option`.

Example:

```
val k: Option[Int] = someFunctionThatMightReturnInvalid()
k match {
    case Some(x) => println(x)
    case None => println("value is invalid")
}
```

Comment: I don't think the code example compiles. Did you mean `val k: Option[Int] = ...`?

Comment: @GaborJuhasz I did indeed!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing a case match and you want to match that a value is actually Some(value) and not None

There are also many cases where you know for sure that a particular value won't be null and you would rather skip the null check that occurs in `Option.apply`

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, null is not suggested to be directly used in Scala, which is why Option/Some/None was introduced. Some(null) is different from Option(null), but I can't see it is useful at all. So  "Some" is only useful in pattern match in real life as previous answers say.

In addition, if you have a chance to learn [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz), which is a functional library for scala, it introduced "some", which behaves like Option in standard scala.

```
scala> import scalaz._; import Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> 2.some
res18: Option[Int] = Some(2)

scala> some(2)
res19: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```