# Why does Some(x).map(_ => null) not evaluate to None?

Tags: scala, option-type

I have recently faced a confusing issue in Scala. I expect the following code to result in `None`, but it results in `Some(null)`:

```
Option("a").map(_ => null)
```

What is the reasoning behind this? Why does it not result in `None`?

Note: This question is not a duplicate of [Why Some(null) isn't considered None?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796616/why-somenull-isnt-considered-none), as that questions asks for explicitly using `Some(null)`. My question is about using `Option.map`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Some(null) isn't considered None?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796616/why-somenull-isnt-considered-none)

Comment: @soon, this isn't a duplicate of that question. That question explicitly asks for Some(null). I already checked that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, not an exactly duplicate, but it covers `Some(null)` behavior which is   closely connected to your question as it used under the hood of the `map` method. I've retracted my vote anyway

Comment: Instance of `Some` is not `None`, as naming suggests. That's why `Some(null)` is _something_ holding `null`, not 'nothing'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the [code for Option `map` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L134-L146):

```
/** Returns a $some containing the result of applying $f to this $option's
 * value if this $option is nonempty.
 * Otherwise return $none.
 *
 *  @note This is similar to `flatMap` except here,
 *  $f does not need to wrap its result in an $option.
 *
 *  @param  f   the function to apply
 *  @see flatMap
 *  @see foreach
 */
@inline final def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] =
  if (isEmpty) None else Some(f(this.get))
```

So, as you can see, if the option is not empty, it will map to `Some` with the value returned by the function. And here is the [code for `Some` class](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L326-L336):

```
/** Class `Some[A]` represents existing values of type
 *  `A`.
 *
 *  @author  Martin Odersky
 *  @version 1.0, 16/07/2003
 */
@SerialVersionUID(1234815782226070388L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
final case class Some[+A](x: A) extends Option[A] {
  def isEmpty = false
  def get = x
}
```

So, as you can see, `Some(null)` will actually create a `Some` object containing `null`. What you probably want to do is use `Option.apply` which does returns a `None` if the value is `null`. Here is the [code for `Option.apply` method](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L19-L25):

```
/** An Option factory which creates Some(x) if the argument is not null,
 *  and None if it is null.
 *
 *  @param  x the value
 *  @return   Some(value) if value != null, None if value == null
 */
def apply[A](x: A): Option[A] = if (x == null) None else Some(x)
```

So, you need to write your code like this:

```
Option("a").flatMap(s => Option.apply(null))
```

Of course, this code makes no sense, but I will consider that you are just doing some kind of experiment.

Comment: Thanks, considering the source code you provided for `Option.map` and `Some`, I can understand why it results this way. I'll accept your answer. Apart from that, though, isn't it confusing this way? Wouldn't it make more sense if it just returned `None` in this case?

Comment: Probably, not `Option("a").map(s => Option.apply(null))`, but `Option("a").flatMap(s => Option.apply(null))` (or even `Option("a").flatMap(s => Option(null))`)?

Comment: Your last statement evaluates to `Some(None)`. which is of type `Option[Option[Nothing]]`. You should use `flatmap` instead as other questions pointed out.

Comment: Corrected. Thanks @maasg.

Answer (score 9):

Every time we add an exception to a rule, we deprive ourselves of a tool for reasoning about code.

Mapping over a `Some` always evaluates to a `Some`. That's a simple and useful law. If we were to make the change you propose, we would no longer have that law. For example, here's a thing we can say with certainty. For all `f`, `x`, and `y`:

```
Some(x).map(f).map(_ => y) == Some(y)
```

If we were to make the change you propose, that statement would no longer be true; specifically, it would not hold for cases where `f(x) == null`.

Moreover, `Option` is a [functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor). Functor is a useful generalization of things that have `map` functions, and it has laws that correspond well to intuition about how mapping should work. If we were to make the change you propose, `Option` would no longer be a functor.

`null` is an aberration in Scala that exists solely for interoperability with Java libraries. It is not a good reason to discard `Option`'s validity as functor.

Comment: Btw, as interesting side note Java's Optional doesn't follow Functor's laws: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-

Answer (score 2):

`Option` is kind of replacement for `null`, but in general you see `null` in scala when you are talking to some java code, it is not like `Option` is supposed to handle `nulls` whenever possible, it is not designed to be used with `nulls` but instead of them. There is however conveniece method `Option.apply` that is similar to java's `Optional.ofNullable` that would handle the `null` case, and that's mostly all about `nulls` and `Options` in scala. In all other cases it works on `Some` and `None` not making any difference if null is inside or not.

If you have some nasty method returning `null` that comes from java and you want to use it directly, use following approach:

```
def nastyMethod(s: String): String = null

Some("a").flatMap(s => Option(nastyMethod(s)))
// or
Some("a").map(nastyMethod).flatMap(Option(_))
```

Both output `Option[String] = None`

So, `nastyMethod` can return a `String` or `null` conceptually is an `Option`, so wrap its result in an `Option` and use it as an `Option`. Don't expect `null` magic will happen whenever you need it.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what's going on, we can use the functional substitution principle to explore the given expression step by step:

```
Option("a").map(s => null) // through Option.apply
Some("a").map(s => null) // let's name the anonymous function as: f(x) = null 
Some("a").map(x => f(x))  // following Option[A].map(f:A=>B) => Option[B]
Some(f("a"))  // apply f(x)
Some(null)
```

The confusion expressed in the question comes from the assumption that the `map` would apply to the argument of the `Option` **before** the `Option.apply` is evaluated:  Let's see how that couldn't possibly work:

```
Option("a").map(x=> f(x)) // !!! can't evaluate map before Option.apply. This is the key to understand !
Option(f(a))              // !!! we can't get here
Option(null)              // !!! we can't get here
None                      // !!! we can't get here
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would it be `None`, the signature of map is a function from a value `A` to `B` to yield an `Option[B]`. No where in that signature does it indicate that `B` may be `null` by saying B is an Option[B]. `flatMap` however does indicate that the values returned is also optional. It's signature is `Option[A] => (A => Option[B]) => Option[B]`.

Comment: So in this case I would expect it to return `Option(null)`, which in turn would give `None`. That is exactly the reason for my confusion.